# MVC Scaffolding View using custom template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have created a custom template as follows:

```
Scaffold CustomTemplate View Index
```

As a result, I now have a local T4 template:

[image]

I made some modifications to the template. My question is how to generate code only for the view. I have done the following which works but which in my opinion is overkill since all I want is for my view to be generated.

```
Scaffold Controller -ModelType Task -ControllerName TasksController -DbContextType TasksDbContext -Repository -Force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find out what command to pass:

```
Scaffold View -ModelType Task -Controller Tasks -ViewName Index -Template Index -Force
```

What I didn't know about was the -Template string switch.